# How do you center an error message created with BootstrapValidate?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

First time using bootstrap and first time asking a question on stackoverflow! I am creating this mockup with forms for email, subject and message. I am also using bootstrap validator to get error messages to pop-up (like ""). but they appear all the way to the left of the window. Anyone know of a way to get the below the input box? Or even above the input box? Like if where says "Email" I would like the error message that says "Please enter a valid email" to pop up right next to it. I've included the html and css. Hopefully I did it right. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form-issue.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/PascaleBeier/bootstrap-validate/v2.2.0/dist/bootstrap-validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contact">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label" for="subject"> Subject </label>
                <input id="subject" class="form-control" type="text" name="subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label" for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        bootstrapValidate('#email', 'email:Please enter a valid email');
        bootstrapValidate('#subject', 'required:Subject is required');
        bootstrapValidate('#message', 'required:Message is required');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
.contact {
    color: white;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    width: 100%;
}

.contact h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 25px;
}

#email,
#subject,
#message {
    width: 30%;
}

.label {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
}

.button {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: fit-content;
    min-height: inherit;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see below example for validation! And add one line style: .invalid-feedback{ width:30%; }

```html
Please see below example for validation! And add one line style: .invalid-feedback{ width:30%; }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/PascaleBeier/bootstrap-validate/v2.2.0/dist/bootstrap-validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            'use strict';
            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            // Loop over them and prevent submission
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
            }, false);
            });
            }, false);
            })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contact">
        <h2>CONTACT</h2>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="label" for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required="">
                <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please enter valid email.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap class "text-center" in class attribute of an element.